# How to filter undefined values from Array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below is working fine it's filtering duplicate values from Array but it's not filtering undefined Values `console.log([67, undefined])`. i want to filter undefined values and duplicate values from array and output in options values as selected. I would be grateful for any help.

i have two datatable with drag and drop functionality. each row of datatable contain the IDs. when i drag the row of table 1 into table 2. the data stored into the Array. i have the addArray function for push the IDs into an Array there also filtering the duplicate IDs and make it uniqueArray. now i want to create the Select option Element which containing the iDs as a value. I want if i drag out a value from Array then the select options update automatically and delete the option from it...?

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    new Sortable(drag, {
        group: 'sortables',
        multiDrag: true, // Enable multi-drag
        selectedClass: 'selected', // The class applied to the selected items
        fallbackTolerance: 3, // So that we can select items on mobile
        animation: 150,
        onUpdate: function (e, tr) {
            addArray();
            checkFields();
        },
    });

    new Sortable(drop, {
        group: "sortables",
        multiDrag: true, // Enable multi-drag
        selectedClass: 'selected', // The class applied to the selected items
        fallbackTolerance: 3, // So that we can select items on mobile
        animation: 150,
        onChange: function (event, tr) {
            Sorting();
            addArray();
            checkFields();
        },
    });


    function addArray() {
        let uniqueArray = [],
            html = [];
        $('#drop').children().each(function () {
            const pk = $(this).data('pk');
            if (pk && !uniqueArray.includes(pk)) {
                uniqueArray.push(pk);
                html.push(`<option value="${pk}">${pk}</option>`);
            }
        });
        $('#id_articles').html(html.join(""))
    }


    function Sorting() {
        sort = [];
        $('#drop').children().each(function () {
            sort.push({ 'pk': $(this).data('pk'), 'order': $(this).index() })
        });
        let crf_token = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').attr('value') // csrf token
        $.ajax({
            url: "/rundown/sorts/",
            type: "post",
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": crf_token },
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {
                'sort': JSON.stringify(sort),
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log('success')
            }
        });
    };

    function checkFields() {
        if ($('#drop tr').length >= 1) {
            $('#drop').find('#blank_row').remove();
        } else {
            $('#drop').append($("<tr>").attr("id", "blank_row")
                .append($('<td>').attr("colspan", '4')
                    .text('Drop here...')));
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: There is no filter in your code. You seem to delete the value and then push it anyway. Why not just NOT push if value is empty/undefined?

Comment: Easier not to add them in first place `...each(funtion() { var pk = $(this).data("pk"); if (pk == undefined) return;` (see other SO questions about better methods to detect undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a filter. Why not just test

```
function stop_duplicate_in_array(array, value) {
  if (!value && value !== 0) return array; // value is falsy but not 0
  if (!array.includes(value)) array.push(value);
  return array;
}
```

if 0 is not a possible value, remove `&& value !== 0`

```
function stop_duplicate_in_array(array, value) {
  if (value && !array.includes(value)) array.push(value);
  return array;
}
```

You can simplify

```js
function addArray() {
  let uniqueArray = [],
    html = [];
  $('#drop').children().each(function() {
    const pk = $(this).data('pk');
    if (pk && !uniqueArray.includes(pk)) {
      uniqueArray.push(pk);
      html.push(`<option value="${pk}">${pk}</option>`);
    }
  });
  $('#id_articles').html(html.join(""))
}
addArray()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop">
  <article data-pk="A">A</article>
  <article>Undefined</article>
  <article data-pk="B">B</article>
  <article data-pk="">Empty</article>
  <article data-pk="C">C</article>
</div>

<select id="id_articles"></select>
```

Comment: would you like to put your code into my code because i don't understand `foo` value

Comment: dear can you apply your code with my code because i don't understand how can i use it

Comment: ok then the in console log is here with your function `(2) [undefined, 67]`

Comment: it's not filtering the unidentified values

Comment: I made a new version for you. It would be MUCH easier if you had posted a [mcve] with relevant HTML

Comment: Dear it's great when i add some values in Array it's also create html elements in select option in html but when i try to delete value from array it's not removing html option element from html what should i do?

Comment: if you want i will ask another Question for you?

Comment: Where do you delete from the array?

Comment: i'm using drag and drop values so if i drag out value from list then i want to remove Select options  also **HMTL**

Comment: My Question is updated please take a look!

Comment: My code updates the select each time addArray is called. So if you remove children from the $("#drop") element, then the select is changed too if you call addArray again

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- Currently you are adding a value, then removing it again in the stop-function, and adding it yet again. True, the values will be unique, but this is not very efficient. Use a Set for efficiently making a collection unique.
- Use jQuery more to the full when creating option elements
- To answer your question: just check for `undefined` before including it. But if you use the Set-way of working (see point 1), you can just *delete* `undefined` from that Set

Here is how it could look:

```js
function addArray() {
    let articles = new Set(
        $('#drop').children().map((i, elem) => $(elem).data('pk')).get()
    );
    articles.delete(undefined);
    $('#id_articles').empty().append(
        Array.from(articles, value => $("<option>", { value }).text(value))
    );
}

addArray();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop">
   <div data-pk="red"></div>
   <div data-pk="blue"></div>
   <div data-pk="red"></div>
   <div></div>
</div>

<select id="id_articles"></select>
```

Comment: dear i don't wanna use append method because in my case the append method it's create duplicate selection option in html side

Comment: your code is working well it's filtering duplicate and unidentified from  Array but not from HTML side because you are using append method

Comment: `append` is fine, because it is preceded by the `empty` method. So it results in the same as your `html` call. Did you really test this with the `empty` method I have in my answer?

Comment: Could you get back to me and confirm you have used `empty` like I have in my answer?

Comment: yes i used your code it's well for stored values in array but in html side it's create duplication option...

Comment: I don't see how that is possible with the code I have provided. You must have done something else. Really, it is impossible with this code. Can you create a fiddle that reproduces that (like on jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: because i'm using drag and drop functionality that's why it's not working for me

Comment: Can you please provide the information either in your question (about the drag & drop event, and preferably a runnable snippet) or else provide a fiddle that reproduces the issue? (Of course, if you are going to drop a duplicate, then you will still get a duplicate, but this code is not going to produce duplicates -- 100% guarantee).

Comment: My Question is updated please take a look!

Comment: I cannot do much with that, as it has dependencies to variables that are not defined (`drag`, `drop`), and I would need to have the HTML as well. In short, it should be possible to just run your code and see what is going on. But I will not insist: you seem to be happy with the other answer as you have accepted it. So I am moving on...

Comment: it's ok Dear thanks for helping for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply compare element with undefined

```js
const array = [1,2,undefined,3,4,undefined,5];
const result = array.filter((el) => el !== undefined);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: it's not work for me can you update it with my code?